# How to fix 'NoneType' object cannot be interpreted as an integer error

Tags: python

When I write it all in my main the program works fine, but when I put it in a function I get this error ('NoneType' object cannot be interpreted as an integer), im guessing it is because of the prompt and the integer mixed.
I saw a lot of similar error in stackoverflow but still could not fix mine.
Any ideas how to fix this?

My function consists of this

```
def take_value(min, max, prompt) :

    value = int(input("input your value"))

    while(value < min or value > max) :
        print("Error – re-enter number (min-max)")
        print(prompt)
        value = int(input("input your value"))
        return value
```

And this is the code line in my main which call the function

```
numCompetitors =take_value(3,16, "Error – Re-enter number of competitors(between 3 and 16 inc)")

for comp in range(0,numCompetitors):
```

Comment: Look at the *exact* line of the error, and work backwards. What is the result of `take_value` in *all possible cases* (such that it affects the value stored in `numCompetitors` and thus the failure in the `range(..)`)? Why/how does the location (and placement) of the `return` affect the possible output? What is the "default" return value of a Python function?

Comment: **tldr;** Minimal failure reproduction: `range(0, None)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def take_value(min, max, prompt) :

    value = int(input("input your value"))

    while(value < min or value > max) :
        print("Error – re-enter number (min-max)")
        print(prompt)
        value = int(input("input your value"))
    return value
```

The return statement should be outside of the loop to ensure that if the first value is valid it would return it.